# TypeError: path.resolve is not a function - Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, rest

I am a beginner in Node.js and following a tutorial.
Here I've write the syntax right but still it's showing the `TypeError` on `path.revole()`.
I've also used the `async/await`.
I wanted to send the `POST` request to the server and server is showing me this on the terminal.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node sr/server.js src/server.js`
Server is listening on PORT ${port}
localhost:${port}
C:\Users\qtmea\Vs Code Files\player_api\src\server.js:31
    const dbLocation = path.resolve("src", "data.json");
                            ^

TypeError: path.resolve is not a function
    at C:\Users\qtmea\Vs Code Files\player_api\src\server.js:31:29
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\qtmea\Vs Code...)
```

> This is my `server.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const shortid = require("shortid");
const fs = require("fs/promises");
const path = require("module")

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/", async(req, res) => {
    const player = {
        ...req.body,
        id: shortid.generate(),
    };
    
    const dbLocation = path.resolve("src", "data.json");      // Here is the error
    const data = await fs.readFile(dbLocation);
    const players = JSON.parse(data);
    players.push(player);

    await fs.writeFile(dbLocation, JSON.stringify(players));
    res.status(201).json(player);
});

app.get("/health",(_req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({status: "OK"});
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on PORT ${port}");
    console.log("localhost:${port}");
});
```

> This is my `apitest.http`

```
GET http://localhost:4000/health

###

POST http://localhost:4000
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Masrafi",
    "country": "BD",
    "rank": 1
}
```

> This is my `data.json`

```
[]
// The output should be like this
// [{" "name": "Masrafi","country": "BD","rank": 1", "id": "WgcNkBGxz"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const path = require("module");
```

to this:

```
const path = require("path");
```

Or, in a modern version of nodejs, use:

```
const path = require("node:path");
```

See relevant nodejs [doc page](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html).